# ip link add gives me an error that it's not supported

Tags: kernel, ip, routing, iproute

I would like to set up a bridge with iproute2 like this:

```
Adding bridge : ip link add name br0 type bridge
Bringing bridge UP : ip link set dev br0 up
Adding interface to bridge : ip link set dev eth1 master br0
Bringing interface UP. : ip link set dev eth1 up
```

But the first line already gives me an error. 
It says:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I found out that it may has something to do with the running kernel.
But I don't know how to check this or edit the file I need to edit.

That's the post where I have the kernel information from:
https://superuser.com/questions/232807/iproute2-not-functioning-rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-supported

Comment: There's not enough information here to begin to troubleshoot your issue. At a bare minimum, your question should include the hardware you're running and the operating system/distro your running, including the kernel version (`uname -a`) and the config file from when it was built.

Comment: A Shot In The Dark (sorry, no Peter Sellers in this one): Have you tried using [bridge-utils](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/bridge-utils.git/about/) to create it rather than [iproute2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/about/)? Usually bridging is handled by a module that loads itself on the first call to `brctl` from the bridge-utils package, so one possible workaround would be to clone the repo and build it in situ.

Also look to see if you have the [ebtables](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/index.html) module loaded. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable Ethernet bridging in Linux kernel as the following.

```
[*] Networking support  --->
 Networking options  --->
  <*> 802.1d Ethernet Bridging
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the OP seems to not have been very experienced on the kernel side of linux (at least the time of posting the question), so you may want to add that the kernel and/or modules will need recompiling afterwards, and possibly add a link to information on how to do it.